# Command embedded in a command

Tags: bash

Struggling to get an embedded command to work in my BASH shell.  I have a feeling it has to do with the 'pic' mark but can't figure it out.

I can make it work embedding $(date +%A).

Thanks!

command:
echo "Today is 'date +%A'." 
results in:
Today is date +%A.

date +%A on it's own works correctly.

[image]

Comment: Use _command substitution_:  `echo "Today is $(date +%A)."`  See `man bash` for details.

Comment: Welcome to U/L. Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086). Please edit your question and replace the image with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using a single quote and not command substitution (aka backtick).

Going with the same idea that you are working with, which is also an equivalent way of doing this as @John1024 comment:

```
echo "Today is `date +%A`"
```

Note the backtick, as opposed to the single quote mark that you originally used.

Comment: Backticks are well known to be an antipattern.

Comment: Whether or not it is an antipattern was not in question. OP was using single quotes, my response corrects that. In addition, I've worked on systems old enough where $() doesn't work, therefore it is still good to see the backtick way.

Comment: how do you type a "backtick"?